Console exit event lasts just 5 seconds
I need to call some functions to stop some processes by clicking the exit button from console and any other key combination.
I've tried to use the SetConsoleCtrlHandler method but the functions called trough this handler don't have time to finish, because after just 5 seconds, the main process is automatically closed.
Is there a solution which ensures that each method called after closing the console has enough time to finish and not just 5 seconds?
Below, the code that I'm using:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Test
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler handler, bool add);

        private delegate bool SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler(CtrlType sig);

        private enum CtrlType
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
        }

        private static bool Handler(CtrlType signal)
        {
            switch (signal)
            {
                case CtrlType.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
                case CtrlType.CTRL_C_EVENT:
                case CtrlType.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
                case CtrlType.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
                case CtrlType.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                    Console.WriteLine("Closing");
                    // TODO Cleanup resources
                    while (true) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    return false;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Register the handler
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(Handler, true);

            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
    }
}


What this while (true) { Thread.Sleep(100); } supposed to do?

This is by design, you've got 5 seconds to do what you need to do.  Take longer and the OS honors the user's request.  No workaround for that.

So the main problem here is that ur console is actually forcibly terminating before the cleanup can occur. The console only has so much time to do any sort of cleanup.
You could solve this by doing this in a seperate thread, but u need to make sure no infinite loops or conflicts occur.
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
public class Test
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler handler, bool add);

    private delegate bool SetConsoleCtrlEventHandler(CtrlType sig);

    private enum CtrlType
    {
        CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
        CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
        CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
        CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
        CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
    }

    private static ManualResetEvent _exitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private static bool Handler(CtrlType signal)
    {
        switch (signal)
        {
            case CtrlType.CTRL_C_EVENT:
            case CtrlType.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
            case CtrlType.CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
            case CtrlType.CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
            case CtrlType.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
                Console.WriteLine("Closing... Starting cleanup.");
                
                // Start cleanup in a new thread
                Thread cleanupThread = new Thread(Cleanup);
                cleanupThread.Start();

                // Doesn't exit b4 cleanup finishes
                _exitEvent.WaitOne();
                
                Console.WriteLine("Cleanup completed. Exiting.");
                Environment.Exit(0);
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Does the cleanup
    private static void Cleanup()
    {
        // resource cleanup here
        ...
        _exitEvent.Set();    // Signal that cleanup is done
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Register the handler
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(Handler, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Application is running. Press Ctrl+C to exit.");
        while (true)
        {
            ... // Simulates the work
        }
    }
}

}
